# RedirectToAction not working when using parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am using asp.net core razor engine entity framework.  I am trying to redirect to another method that has a parameter, however I keep getting a localhost page can't be found message.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to redirect from my Update method into my LookUpItem method.

Here is my code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("LookUpItem/{id}")]
    public IActionResult LookUpItem(int id)
    {
        var user = _context.Auction.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        ViewData["Product"] = user.Product;
        ViewData["user"] = user.First_Name_Of_Seller;
        var timeLeft = user.End_Date.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        ViewData["Description"] = user.Description;
        ViewData["HighestBid"] = user.Bid;
        ViewData["NameOfBidder"] = user.First_Name_Highest_Bid + " " + user.Last_Name_Highest_Bid;

        HttpContext.Session.SetString("item_id", id.ToString());
        if (timeLeft.Days > 0)
        {
            ViewData["EndDate"] = (@timeLeft.Days + " Days");
        }
        else if (timeLeft.Hours > 0)
        {
            ViewData["EndDate"] = (@timeLeft.Hours + " Hours");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["EndDate"] = (@timeLeft.Minutes + " Minutes");
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("update")]
    public IActionResult Update(Auction item)
    {
        string LocalVariable = HttpContext.Session.GetString("item_id");
        System.Console.WriteLine("?????????????");
        System.Console.WriteLine( LocalVariable);
        System.Console.WriteLine("?????????????");
        return RedirectToAction("LookUpItem",new {@id = Int32.Parse(LocalVariable)});//Trying to call the above method
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to redirect to a `HttpPost` action.  Do you mean a `HttpGet LookUpItem`?  You cannot redirect to a `HttpPost` action. Also there is no need for the `@` symbol in the `routeValues` section of the `RedirectToAction` method

Comment: Hello,  have you to remove httppost from the above method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP doesn't support redirection to a page using POST.

> Controller.RedirectToAction: Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to redirect to a `[HttpPost]` action.  You need to redirect to a `[HttpGet]` action.

Also there is no need for the `@` symbol in the `routeValues` portion of the `RedirectToAction`.. Also, this might just be me, but why can't you do the parse before instead of trying to *shortcut* the process and combining it all into one method.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("update")]
public IActionResult Update(Auction item)
{
    string LocalVariable = HttpContext.Session.GetString("item_id");
    System.Console.WriteLine("?????????????");
    System.Console.WriteLine( LocalVariable);
    System.Console.WriteLine("?????????????");
    var intParse = Int32.Parse(LocalVariable);
    return RedirectToAction("LookUpItem",new {id = intParse});
}

[HttpGet] //change to HttpGet
[Route("LookUpItem/{id}")]
public IActionResult LookUpItem(int id)
{
    // logic here
    return View();
}
```

Let me know if this helps